# "this post contains a blocked URL" error in FB application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My webhost is 000webhost.com
I've set up an FB app which needs to post on the user's wall. But FB gives this error
"this post contains a blocked URL".

Here is my code

```
require_once("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret, 'cookie' => true ));


$attachment =  array(
        'access_token' => $params['access_token'],
        'message' => "Hello, here is a post",
        'name' => "",
        'link' => "http://www.facebook.com",
        'description' => "Write here your description",
        );

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

What is wrong? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Pay attention to the actual error message - you are using a "blocked URL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to link to facebook.com. Also you dont need to set the accestoken if the user is already loggedin in your application. Try another url:

```
require_once("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret, 'cookie' => true ));


$attachment =  array(
        'message' => "Hello, here is a post",
        'name' => "",
        'link' => "http://www.example.com",
        'description' => "Write here your description",
        );

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

Comment: i still get the error "Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Sorry, this post contains a blocked UR"

Comment: maybe example.com is blocked too. use your own url to test.